# Call a function from a sibling component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider the following. You are building a reusable item carousel. For that the requirements are that the slide track component and the slide navigation component have to be independent and in a sibling relationship so you can place the buttons where you like. How can I now trigger let's say the moveForward function in the slide track component when I click the button in the slide navigation component?

I have a solution but it is not very elegant. Basically I store some state in the parent that changes if the button is clicked, and listen to that in the slide track via an effect.

In the parent:

```
export const ParentWithSlider: React.FC = () => {
 const [moveForward, setMoveForward] = React.useState(false)
 const [moveBackward, setMoveBackward] = React.useState(false)
 return <section>
  <ItemSliderButtons
    setMoveBackward={setMoveBackward}
    setMoveForward={setMoveForward}
  />
  <ItemSlider
    setMoveBackward={setMoveBackward}
    setMoveForward={setMoveForward}
    moveForward={moveForward}
    moveBackward={moveBackward}
   >
 </section>
}
```

And then in the item slider component I do something like this

```
React.useEffect(() => {
 if (props.moveForward) {
  // calls the forward implementation in the item slider 
  triggerMyForwardFunc()

  props.setMoveForward(false)
 }
}, [props.moveForward])
```

I feel like there must be a better way. Keep in mind the item slider button component cannot be a child of the item slider component.

Comment: Consider using events. It is more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ItemSlider` can expose the functions with [`useImperativeHandler`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useImperativeHandle):

```
const ItemSlider = forwardRef((props, ref) {
  const forward = () => /* forward logic */;
  
  const backward = () => /* backward logic */;

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    forward,
    backward,
  }), [])
  ...
})
```

The parent assigns a `ref` to `ItemSlider`, and you can use the functions directly in `ItemSliderButtons`:

```
export const ParentWithSlider: React.FC = () => {
  const ref = useRef();

 return <section>
  <ItemSliderButtons
    backward={() => ref.current?.backward()}
    forward={() => ref.current?.forward()}
  />
  <ItemSlider ref={ref}>
 </section>
}
```